# What is a leap year in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, word-request, calendarium

Now that it's 29th of February, there is no way not to ask:
What is a leap year in Latin?

Leap month and leap day (*mensis/dies intercalaris* or *intercalarius*) are well attested.
In the Julian calendar a leap day is added every four years, whereas before Caesar's reform a whole month was added when needed.
But is there a name for the year that contains an added month or day?

*Annus intercalaris* would make sense, but I fear that it might mean "an added year" rather than "a year with something added".
Is there an established expression for a leap year in Latin of any era?
What would be a reasonable way to express it?

Comment: llmavirta: Glosbe "leap year": "annus bisextus"; bisextus being an intercalary i.e. something inserted between other things: "annus intercalarius"; a year + additional day, "annus bisextilis". Unusually, for Glosbe, no attestations were offered. On Wiktionary, a quote from 1553 which ends: "...quartus vero, ex 366 diebus componitur, et bisextilis nuncupatur." = "...while the fourth (year), composed of 366 days, is called bissextile.). Pock. Ox. Dict. gives "bisextilis annus" (masculine). Is it your birthday, today? If so Happy Birthday; if not, please ignore this impertinence.

Comment: Does *Annus saltus* seem reasonable?

Comment: @Allawonder Possibly, but you'd have to argue why it makes sense. I don't recall seeing that in Latin. It looks like a direct translation from English, and not all languages relate leap years to jumping. But whatever the reasoning might be, I'd be happy to see it fleshed out as an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As for the Gregorian calendar, the source is indeed (Ecclesiastical) Latin:

> Deinde, ne in posterum a XII Kalendas Aprilis æquinoctium recedat, **statuimus bissextum quarto quoque anno** (uti mos est) continuari debere, præterquam in centesimis annis; qui, quamvis **bissextiles** antea semper fuerint, qualem etiam esse volumus annum MDC, post eum tamen qui deinceps consequentur centesimi non omnes **bissextiles** sint, sed in quadringentis quibusque annis primi quique tres centesimi **sine bissexto** transigantur, quartus vero quisque centesimus **bissextilis** sit, ita ut annus MDCC, MDCCC, MDCCCC **bissextiles** non sint. Anno vero MM, more consueto **dies bissextus** intercaletur, Februario dies XXIX continente, idemque ordo intermittendi intercalandique **bissextum diem** in quadringentis quibusque annis perpetuo conservetur. (Inter Gravissimas, 9).

[Inter Gravissimas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter_gravissimas) is the papal bull that established the current (i.e., Gregorian) calendar.

English translation by Spencer (1999):

> Then, lest the equinox recede from XII calends April [March 21st] in the future, **we establish every fourth year to be bissextile** (as the custom is), except in centennial years ;  which always were **bissextile** until now; we wish that year 1600 is still **bissextile**; after that, however, those centennial years that follow are not all **bissextile**, but in each four hundred years, the first three centennial years are not **bissextile**, and the fourth centennial year, however, is **bissextile**, so the years 1700, 1800 and 1900 will not be **bissextile**.  Assuredly, the year 2000, as with our custom, will have a **bissextile** intercalation, February will contain 29 days, and the same rule of intermittent **bissextile** intercalations in each four hundred year period will be preserved in perpetuity.

Both the original Latin text and English translation (and also one to French) may be found [here](http://www.bluewaterarts.com/calendar/NewInterGravissimas.htm).

Here we see both **bissextus** and **bissextilis**. It seems to me that the former is preferred for the day and the latter for the year. (For this to be true, the translation of the relevant portion of the first sentence would be something like *we establish that there must continue to be a leap **day** every four years*.)

---

**Addendum:** As pointed by Vincenzo Oliva and tchrist in the comments, it is worth noting that **bissextus** literally means *twice-sixth*, as it was originally used to designate the intercalary day in the Julian calendar, that Julius decided to be the repetition (hence **bis-**) of the sixth day before the kalends of March (i.e., the 24th of February).

Comment: Side comment: this also adds to the answer of [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/241/how-to-say-every-fourth-year-in-latin/887)

Comment: +1. Note that the terms have Roman origins, related to the original Roman calendar. See [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/bissextile-), perhaps you could summarize and integrate this in your answer.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva Agree that it’s worth explaining why Caesar’s *bissext* (a largely forgotten and obsolete word in English today, though *bissextile* remains) was actually a “double-sixth” day before the March Kalends and so was considered to double the **24ᵗʰ** of February rather than the 28ᵗʰ as we would now reckon it.

Comment: just wanted to mention that the Russian word *високосный* for "leap (year)" originates from "bissextus"

Comment: Bissextile is a great word, but pretty much obsolete in English, at least according to [google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bissextile&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbissextile%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Neo-Latin Lexicon](http://neolatinlexicon.org/search/latin?search=leap%20year) a leap year is *annus intercalaris* or *annus bisextilis*.

Answer (score 1):

The Roman annus bisextilis (bisextile year) has an extra day (bis VI Kal Mar = 24 February) preceding VI Kal Mar = 25 February. Hence its name.